# Double free or corruption error in python

Tags: python, pygame, sigabrt, replit, double-free

I am using pygame on replit and am getting an unsual error.

This error usually comes from a c or c++ compiler when you attempt to free the same memory twice, but this is python. I think it is a replit issue because the error doesn't happen in atom using my python install. Here is the full error:

```
double free or corruption (!prev)
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7f20afd05baa m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610
signal arrived during cgo execution

goroutine 1 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0x4bb800, 0xc000061cd8)
    runtime/cgocall.go:156 +0x5c fp=0xc000061cb0 sp=0xc000061c78 pc=0x40651c
main._Cfunc_pry_eval_file(0x1ca4c10, 0x1ccf930, 0x1, 0x1d130e0)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:562 +0x4c fp=0xc000061cd8 sp=0xc000061cb0 pc=0x4b944c
main.Python.EvalFile.func5(0x1d130e0, 0x8, {0xc000012230, 0x0, 0x40ced5}, 0x0)
    github.com/replit/prybar/languages/python3/main.go:92 +0x75 fp=0xc000061d28 sp=0xc000061cd8 pc=0x4ba455
main.Python.EvalFile({}, {0x7fff05d4a31d, 0x7}, {0xc000012230, 0x0, 0x0})
    github.com/replit/prybar/languages/python3/main.go:92 +0x20c fp=0xc000061de0 sp=0xc000061d28 pc=0x4ba22c
main.(*Python).EvalFile(0x5d56d0, {0x7fff05d4a31d, 0x5d56d0}, {0xc000012230, 0x0, 0xc00007f110})
    <autogenerated>:1 +0x45 fp=0xc000061e18 sp=0xc000061de0 pc=0x4bb265
github.com/replit/prybar/utils.Language.EvalFile({{0x5075d0, 0x5d56d0}, {0x7fff05d4a307, 0xc000064100}}, {0x7fff05d4a31d, 0x7}, {0xc000012230, 0x0, 0x0})
    github.com/replit/prybar/utils/language.go:86 +0xa2 fp=0xc000061e78 sp=0xc000061e18 pc=0x4b8102
github.com/replit/prybar/utils.DoCli({0x5075d0, 0x5d56d0})
    github.com/replit/prybar/utils/utils.go:67 +0x2e8 fp=0xc000061f60 sp=0xc000061e78 pc=0x4b89a8
main.main()
    github.com/replit/prybar/languages/python3/generated_launch.go:7 +0x27 fp=0xc000061f80 sp=0xc000061f60 pc=0x4b8bc7
runtime.main()
    runtime/proc.go:255 +0x227 fp=0xc000061fe0 sp=0xc000061f80 pc=0x436d67
runtime.goexit()
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581 +0x1 fp=0xc000061fe8 sp=0xc000061fe0 pc=0x462e41

rax    0x0
rbx    0x6
rcx    0x7f20afd05baa
rdx    0x0
rdi    0x2
rsi    0x7fff05d48c40
rbp    0x7fff05d48f80
rsp    0x7fff05d48cb8
r8     0x0
r9     0x7fff05d48c40
r10    0x8
r11    0x200246
r12    0x7fff05d48ea0
r13    0x1000
r14    0x2
r15    0x7f2086992000
rip    0x7f20afd05baa
rflags 0x200246
cs     0x33
fs     0x0
gs     0x0
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 2
```

The error gives no indication of what is causing the error so I have included the full code bellow. The change that made this start happening was adding the `-1`s to lines 69, 71 and 73.

```
import pygame, random, math
pygame.init()
WIN_SIZE = (640, 480)
win = pygame.display.set_mode(WIN_SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Anti-aliasing")
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
win.fill(WHITE)

class point:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
class lineSegment:
  def __init__(self, p1, p2):
    self.p1 = p1
    self.p2 = p2
    self.v = point(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y)
  def hray(self, y):
    if self.v.y == 0: return None
    n = (y - self.p1.y)/self.v.y
    if not 0<=n<=1: return None
    return self.p1.x + self.v.x * n
  def vray(self, x):
    if self.v.x == 0: return None
    n = (x - self.p1.x)/self.v.x
    if not 0<=n<=1: return None
    return self.p1.y + self.v.y * n
class tri:
  def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3):
    self.p1 = p1
    self.p2 = p2
    self.p3 = p3
    self.l1 = lineSegment(p2, p3)
    self.l2 = lineSegment(p3, p1)
    self.l3 = lineSegment(p1, p2)
    left = min(p1.x, p2.x, p3.x)
    top = min(p1.y, p2.y, p3.y)
    right = max(p1.x, p2.x, p3.x)
    bottom = max(p1.y, p2.y, p3.y)
    self.bounds = pygame.Rect(left, top, right - left, bottom - top)
  def hray(self, y):
    output = []
    l1r = self.l1.hray(y)
    if l1r != None:
      output.append(l1r - self.bounds.x)
    l2r = self.l2.hray(y)
    if l2r != None:
      output.append(l2r - self.bounds.x)
    l3r = self.l3.hray(y)
    if l3r != None:
      output.append(l3r - self.bounds.x)
    
    if len(output) == 0: return None
    if len(output) == 1:
      print("fuck")
      return None
    #print([min(output), max(output)])
    return [min(output), max(output)]
    
  def draw(self):
    surf = pygame.Surface((self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height), flags = pygame.SRCALPHA)
    array = pygame.PixelArray(surf)
    for y in range(self.bounds.height):
      mHray = self.hray(y + self.bounds.y)
      if mHray != None:
        array[round(mHray[0])-1 : round(mHray[1]), y] = BLACK
        shade = math.ceil(255 * (mHray[0]%1))
        array[round(mHray[0])-1 , y] = (shade, shade, shade)
        shade = math.ceil(255 * (mHray[1]%1))
        array[round(mHray[1])-1 , y] = (shade, shade, shade)
    array.close()
    win.blit(surf, (self.bounds.x, self.bounds.y))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, GREEN, self.bounds, 1)
    pygame.draw.circle(win, RED, (self.p1.x, self.p1.y), 2)
    pygame.draw.circle(win, RED, (self.p2.x, self.p2.y), 2)
    pygame.draw.circle(win, RED, (self.p3.x, self.p3.y), 2)
p1 = point(random.randrange(0, WIN_SIZE[0]), random.randrange(0, WIN_SIZE[1]))
p2 = point(random.randrange(0, WIN_SIZE[0]), random.randrange(0, WIN_SIZE[1]))
p3 = point(random.randrange(0, WIN_SIZE[0]), random.randrange(0, WIN_SIZE[1]))
mTri = tri(p1, p2, p3)
mTri.draw()
pygame.display.update()
print("done")
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 the error shares nothing about where the error is coming from and I've never seen this error before so as far as I'm concerned this is the shortest possible code to generate this error

Comment: its caused by code, so I consider it and error in the code, and in my opinion which is objectively wrong repl.it is very convenient because someone trying to answer my question can click a link and immediately run the code and reproduce the error, besides, the error only happens in repl.it so there isn't much point people copy pasting code from a post because they'd have to put it into repl.it anyway

Comment: thanks for your helpful feed back, but can you suggest a better place to ask this question

Comment: ok, fair enough, im sorry, are you trying to reproduce it in replit

Comment: I see a black tringle with red dots at the corners in a green frame. The triangle is different after each launch. (no crash 10 times in a row)

Comment: is the crash not happening even after multiple runs and are you using replit

Comment: No crash 10 times in a row and I just follow your link and press play.

Comment: If there is a problem in the code, it may be easier to find the problem by debugging it in another IDE.

Comment: I just tried it and it happened on 5th run

Comment: So there is a problem in the code. Use a different IDE and a debugger to find the problem. If it really is a problem with the code, the information about replit.com is completely irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem in another IDE.

Comment: Interestingly I managed to get to break on the command line:

`pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.6.9)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
double free or corruption (!prev)
Aborted (core dumped)`  Only about every one-in-six runs.

Comment: What version of Python / PyGame are you using ?

Comment: python 3.8.12 pygame 2.1.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've done a lot of debugging and I think I know what the problem is, because of faulty conversion from precise float coordinates to array coordinates a negative result can sometimes be outputed, or worse but this doesn't seem to bother pygame as much, a slice can be taken where the upper coordinate is lower than the lower coordinate. I'm guessing that pygame's indexing function can't cope with this and doesn't know what error to give. I'm honestly not sure how to fix the issue as it occurs in an edge case where I'm not sure myself what it should do, in any case I consider this question closed.